# Python/Excel: Compare the given value with the summed value

Tags: python, excel, if-statement, for-loop, sum

[Excel Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALvVn.png)

From "Excel Image 1", I am pulling data into python of Column A and Column B. The goal is to sum the values of Column B, and see whether it is higher or lower than the given sum of 1500. If it is higher or equal to 1500, then there needs to be nothing done. But, if it is lower, then adjust the values that has the word "change" beside them, such that the calculated sum becomes 1500 or more. In our case, the sum is 700, which is lower than 1500.

```
import xlrd
excel = '/Users/Bob/Desktop/'

wb1 = xlrd.open_workbook(excel + 'assignment2.xlsx')
sh1 = wb1.sheet_by_index(0)

colA,colB = [],[]
for a in range(3,sh1.nrows):
    colA.append(int(sh1.cell(a,0).value))
    colB.append(int(sh1.cell(a,1).value))
print(colA)
print(colB)

excel_sum=(sh1.cell_value(2,1))
print("Given Sum:", excel_sum)

calc_sum = sum(colB)
print(calc_sum)

if calc_sum >= excel_sum:
    print("Good")
#else:
#Need to adjust the values that has the words "change" beside them
```

Current Output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
[900, -400, -200, 300, 100]
Given Sum: 1500.0
700
```

Thanks!

Comment: So is the "change" in column C? And the goal is reduce the total of column B to be 1500 or more after the change, then what is the algorithm of change (uniformly adjust across all changed cells, bring all change cells to same value to reach goal)?

Comment: No. The 1500 given in B3 is just telling us that, that is the sum we should have when we add B4 to B8. But, we don't have that when we add them. We only have 700. Therefore, we need to adjust the B6 and B8 because C6 and C8 has the word "change", such that when we add them again, the sum is 1500 or more. There should if-else statements  i believe to compare the sum with the given sum.

Comment: @ChrisFreeman Does that make sense?

Comment: How should the adjustment be made? Spread the different evenly among all `change` elements? Or in proportion to their values? Or ...?

Comment: @Austin Hastings It doesn't matter how you do it as long the values you change them are positive, and we are only changing the values in B6 and B8 because we are only allowed to change them according to cells C6 and C8. This code should work for any excel file with the same format.

Comment: Then it seems like you know the delta, so you could just scan column C, find the first "change", and add that delta to the value in B, right?

Answer (score 0):

You know the delta - `excel_sum - calc_sum`. So scan column C for a change, and add it to column B.

```
else:
    for row in range(3, sh1.nrows):
        if sh1.cell(row, 2) == 'change':
            colB[row] = int(sh1.cell(row, 1)) + excel_sum - calc_sum
            break
```

Of course, I see you using `xlrd` but not `xlwt`, so I don't know how you're going to change the value. Do you?

Comment: SET_CELL_VALUE is undefined. Once I change it, I want the code to calculate the sum again, and this time it will be equal to 1500. I think we will need to using xlwt to write those new into those cells beside the question mark.

Comment: Correct. You'll have to figure out how to get xlwt and xlrd to work together, and code the SET_CELL_VALUE according to your plan. From what I read, most use cases for xlrd and xlwt are as a filter, so you would be copying cell values and then changing some. But there are probably other usages.

Comment: I am not allowed to make changes in the excel file though. What I have here is not what I am actually doing. I have made an example myself and posted it. What I have actually uses a formula. So, I would appreciate if you make this fully work.

Comment: Okay, I've modified it to change colB directly. That's the only other place where the column values are stored.

Comment: Where is the new array with new values that adds up to 1500 ? I mean what and how do I print what you have coded?

Comment: I just had it modify colB. So you should be able to add up colB to get 1500 afterwards.

Comment: I get that. But, i want to see it printed. When I do `print(colB)`, it is printing the old colB. I want to name the updated colB, such that when I printing something like `print(new_colB)`, I should see the results of that else statement. Same thing with calc_sum.